# Does Google App Engine keep code snapshots of past deployments?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've deployed code changes to a GAE app under development and broken the app.  My IDE isn't tracking history to the point in time where things still worked, and I didn't commit my code to a repo as often as I updated the app, so I can't be sure what the state of the deployed code was at the point in time when it was working, though I do know a date when it was working.  Is there a way to either:

1. Rollback the app to a specific date?
2. See what code was deployed at a specific deployment or date?

I see that deployments are logged - I'm hoping that GAE keeps a copy of code for each deployment allowing me to at least see the code or diffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only see which version of your app was deployed and when - unless you deleted the older version.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can only download the latest deployed app source code for any given version of the app. Did you deploy your code to a version (while it was working) which hasn't been overwritten since ? If so, you can use the command

```
   appcfg.py download_app -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> <output_dir>
```

to download that source code.

Comment: Saddly it's always been deployed to the same version number.   thanks for the tip though!